# HTML help displaying more than one row in a resultset

Tags: java, html

Ok I have looked and looked lol I am having problems. This is the last part of my code that displays the filmography of actors, I have built an SQL database that has this information inside of it. Though when I display as a web page I am only seeing one film per actor where some of them have at least three any suggestions or help ? hope this is not dumb lol I am pretty new at this.

```
<h3><FONT COLOR="B22222">Filmography</FONT></h3>
<%
newaid = request.getParameter("selectedName");

String queryFilm = "SELECT * FROM artist, movies, artistmovie WHERE  artistmovie.mid = movies.mid AND artist.aid = artistmovie.aid AND artist.aid = '"; 
    queryFilm += request.getParameter("selectedName") + "';";

ResultSet rsFilm = stm.executeQuery(queryFilm);

while(rsFilm.next())
{
    title = rsFilm.getString("title");
    studio = rsFilm.getString("studio");
    rlsdate = rsFilm.getString("rlsdate");
    role = rsFilm.getString("role");
    oscar = rsFilm.getInt("oscar");
    }

    out.println("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" + title + "</td>");
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>(" + studio + "</a></td>"); 
    out.println("<td></td><td>" + rlsdate + ")</td>");  
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" + role + "</td>");
if (oscar == 0)
{
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;</td><td><br /></td>");
}
else
{
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;</td><td>Won oscar</td></tr>");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't seen a `<font>` tag in years. Hat's off to you, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this you're closing the while statement before printing the data. Try this:

```
while(rsFilm.next())
{
    title = rsFilm.getString("title");
    studio = rsFilm.getString("studio");
    rlsdate = rsFilm.getString("rlsdate");
    role = rsFilm.getString("role");
    oscar = rsFilm.getInt("oscar");

    out.println("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" + title + "</td>");
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>(" + studio + "</a></td>"); 
    out.println("<td></td><td>" + rlsdate + ")</td>");  
    out.println("<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" + role + "</td>");
}
```